# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Cos' when running inference on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I've trained a TensorFlow model that among other things performs input preparation involving a `tf.cos` operation. I've now integrated this model into an Android application, but it cannot perform inference and produces an error `No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Cos'` (full error below).

What I've tried:

1. I've built a [selective registration header](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header.py) and  made sure that `ops_to_register.h` contains the `Cos` operator
2. I've rebuilt `libtensorflow_inference.so` as suggested [in a related TensorFlow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14158) while making sure that `ops_to_register.h` is being used while building the `.so` file
3. I placed the new `libtensorflow_inference.so` file in my app's `app/src/main/jniLibs/<architecture>` while makings sure that the new `.so` file is being used by the app

I still get the same error.

Also, not sure if this is related, but `cwise_op_cos.cc` is missing in [tf_op_files.txt](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt) and [BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD).

Is there something I'm doing wrong? How do I get the `tf.cos` operation to work on Android?

Here's the relevant excerpt from the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Cos' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

 [[Node: stft/hann_window/Cos = Cos[T=DT_FLOAT](stft/hann_window/truediv)]]
  at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
  at org.tensorflow.Session.access$100(Session.java:48)
  at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.runHelper(Session.java:298)
  at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.run(Session.java:248)
  at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:228)
  at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:197)
  at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.run(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:187)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is indeed necessary to add these commands to the BUILD (tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD) file manually.

So, for example, to include `tf.cos` opperation into your `libtensorflow_inference.so` you need to do the following:

1. Make sure `|| isequal(op, "Cos")` is in the `ops_to_register.h` file (see my explanation above)
2. Add `cwise_op_cos.cc` to `android_extended_ops_group1` filegroup in tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD
3. `bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so ...` for the right architecture

Later I even found that one of the TensorFlow developers suggested that hacking the BUILD file is the recommended way in this case :/

> Android only builds a subset of the ops, You need to add the ops that
>   you need that are not in the "commonly used set" by hacking the build
>   files for your needs.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11804#issuecomment-318415228